# Passing req.user to graphQL

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, passport.js

I am new to GraphQL and have some experience with Node.

I am logging in a user using passport in my application hence my `req` will appended with `req.user` in my express containing user info.

Now, Since I am using GraphQL, How can I pass req.user to GraphQL from my main App? (or GraphQL will by itself have access to req and hence req.user?)

I have a simple GraphQL Schema like this

```
app.use("/graphql", expressGraphQL({
    schema: schema,
    graphiql: true
  }));
```

For Starters, I wasn't able to find any tutorial authenticating user with passport so I thought about using restful APi routes to authenticate my user using passport and then passing req.user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put user stuff into `context`

```
app.use("/graphql", expressGraphQL({
    schema: schema,
    graphiql: true,
    context: ({ req }) => ({
      user: req.user
    })
}));
```

And get context in resolver.
Every resolver in a GraphQL.js schema accepts four positional arguments:

`fieldName(obj, args, context, info) { result }`

Answer (score 1):

Using `"graphql": "^14.0.2"` in node, I was able to just use `req` as a resolver param like so (without any other special config in the `app.use` section):

```
 fieldName(args, req) {
    console.log(req.user);
 }
```